# How to set Route Patterns in MultiSelect Master List?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

[image]

I have a master list in master-detail app, when I set it to multi-select mode, I want to capture userIds of all the selected item. Is there any elegant way to pass these data to `detail.controller.js` through route?

my showDetail function in single select master page(`"pattern": "User/{objectId}"`):

```
this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
    objectId : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("ID")
});
```

Should I use `User/{objectIdArray}`, `User/id1/id2/...` or something? Will it looks strange in URL?

Ref: [Route Pattern Examples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.PatternMatching/preview)

Comment: What is the intention of multi select? According to the guidelines this application type should be used to select one item to be shown in the detail: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/split-screen/

Comment: I want to show info of all the selected items in detail page. So it is not permitted?

Comment: You shouldn't care too much about the look of your URL. One idea: Concatenate your IDs with a simple separator (eg "User/001,002,003") and split that string in your Detail.controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marc, below is my Code:

manifest.json:

```
           {
                "pattern": "MultiSelect/{objectIds}",
                "name": "multi",
                "target": [
                    "master",
                    "multi"
                ]
            }
```

Master.controller.js

```
         _showDetail : function (oItem) {
            const masterModel = this._oList.getMode();

            if(masterModel === "None") {
                this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
                    objectId : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("userID")
                }, false);
            } else { //MultiSelect Mode
                const lists = this._oList.getSelectedItems(),
                ids = lists.map(item => item.getBindingContext().getProperty("userID"));

                this.getRouter().navTo("multi", {
                    objectIds : JSON.stringify(ids)
                }, true);
            }
        },
```

MultiUser.controller.js

```
        _onMultiMatched : function (oEvent) {
            const sObjectIds =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectIds,
            idArray = JSON.parse(sObjectIds);
            //... Do whatever I like
        }
```